# Why footer is included into container?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is visible here:
http://aivarasdaukantas.lt/demo/2015/12/15/testinis-postas-numeris-vienas/
The footer must be full width.
The page code:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <div class="container"> 
   <div class="row"  style="padding-top:40px">
        <div class="col-md-2"><?php the_post_thumbnail ('medium', array( 'class' => 'img-square img-responsive' ));?></div>
        div class="col-md-8">
        <h2><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h2>
        <h2><small><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ?></small></h2>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?></p>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #cccccc">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
       </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php comments_template(); ?>
```

I dont get why the footer is included into container?

Footer code:

```
    <nav id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pull-left fnav">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right fnav">
                <ul class="footer-social">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing a `<` before your `col-md-8` (and a closing `</div>` probably), but you also don't close your `<nav>` so that's where the footer ends up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to end the `<nav id="footer"> </nav>` right before wp_footer();
Also missing `<` before your `col-md-8`

Hopefully this helps i'm not sure.